# Datatables error with accents in the rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

When I go to the page where there is a customer who has an accented letter in a field or I look for it from the table's search bar, I get an error as if he couldn't load the page because of the accent. I tried various plugins but they don't solve the problem. I would like to avoid replacing for example the " ì " with " i' ". Do you have any solutions about it?

I would like to display the table with accented letters without any problem.

My PDO config:

```
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";charset=utf8mb4;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
//$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You won't find a plugin for accents, such a tool would be unnecessary. You need to ensure you are using UTF-8 everywhere.

Comment: "_I get an error_" - Can you provide error details and also provide a [mre], so the problem can be recreated? Add the MRE to the question (for example, as a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/12567365).)

Comment: Sorry, I add more information. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you create a [mre]?

Comment: I can't recreate the problem. I don't understand if it is a data problem when I use them in PHP (and passing them to the datatable) or it is a problem with my PHP config. If I use " i' " instead of " ì" or " e' " instead of " è " datatable work fine therefore this is a problem with accents.